# Flask - Gevent Error

Tags: python, gevent

I came across the following error, while trying to start a Flask-GEvent app.

My OS - W7 64 bit

```
C:\Users\raghul\workspace\test>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from views import app
  File "C:\Users\raghul\workspace\test\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from socketio.server import SocketIOServer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gevent
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gevent import core
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch between the Python binary and the gevent DLL.

My guess is that your Python is 64-bit and you installed the 32-bit Gevent. If this is the case, then uninstall gevent and then download the 64-bit version [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gevent). Alternatively you can install Python 32-bit and then install the official Gevent installer on it.